# Temporary variable without backing bean?

Tags: java, jsf-2

I'm trying to make a temp var in a JSF page. I want to use it to store a i18n key that is needed to be passed further in some of the ongoing expressions.

But how can I make a temp var?
This does not work:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="10" scope="page"/>
<h:outputText value="#{myVar}" />
```

Just is empty. Nothing is printed from the outputText.

How can I do?
ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `<ui:param` instead

```
<ui:param name="myVar" value="10"></ui:param>
<h:outputText value="#{myVar}" />
```